# Optimizing the redirect code

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, optimization

I found this from a shortcode and we're having a bit of an issue with the loading time using this function. I was wondering if there's a way to further optimize this or perhaps use a php redirection instead of javascript?

```
function gdp_mss_after_login() {
$user = wp_get_current_user();

if( $user && is_object( $user ) && is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) ) {

    $user_level = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'gdp_level', true);

    ob_start();

    if ( !empty($user_level) ) {
        $post_id = get_option('gdp_mss_course_level_' . $user_level);
        $url = esc_url(get_permalink($post_id));
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location = '<?php echo $url; ?>';
        </script>
        <?php
    }

}
return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'gdp_mss_login_redirect', 'gdp_mss_after_login' );
```

Comment: why not wp_redirect()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [wp_redirect()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)

```
function gdp_mss_after_login() {
  $user = wp_get_current_user();
  if( $user && is_object( $user ) && is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) ) {
    $user_level = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'gdp_level', true);
    if ( !empty($user_level) ) {
        $post_id = get_option('gdp_mss_course_level_' . $user_level);
        $url = esc_url(get_permalink($post_id));
        wp_redirect($url);
    }else{
       return false;
    }
  }
}
add_shortcode( 'gdp_mss_login_redirect', 'gdp_mss_after_login' );
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh. Doesn't seem to be working. The redirection for some reason is not happening. Anything I'm missing?